# Is Dart complete end to end web application solution?

Tags: dart

I am completely new to dart, i never done any programs in dart, but i am curious and have few questions, I understand dart can run in server side as well, so is that mean it is not only the client side programming (like javascript), as well we can write some server side code as well ? (Like java),

in that case when i go for enterprise level big applications, does dart depends on any server side languages like Java?, and what is the level of database support with Dart?

May be the question would be what it can or can't do in web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. Though not perfectly worded, I think the basic question as to what part of the web development stack the Dart language fits is a reasonable question. In fact, I am here because I had that question and the answer provided was very helpful. I don't see anything in the question that will case arguments or debates. Where Dart fits in the web development stack is a very black and white question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart runs serverside in a VM. You will be able to run a dart application  on a webServer and also access files on that Server. There is a library [dart:io](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_io.html) which allows you to do that. IO works only serverside.
Dart does not need Java or any other language to work. You have the Dart VM (serverside) and clientside your dartcode will be compiled with dart2js to javascript.

There are few projects that deal with databases. But from my understanding there is nothing yet out there that is really awesome.

Just search for Database Drivers here: http://blog.dartwatch.com/p/community-dart-packages-and-examples.html